# unity build error Failed to find:AndroidTargetDevice

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, export, build.gradle

I want to export apk file in unity.I use sdk file that I use for android developing.
but when I export this error happen:"Failed to find:AndroidTargetDevice
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)"

I changned my sdk address and use different sdk but does not work.
please help me guys!
[image]